# Cut Typed Line Numbers From Multiple Lines in a Text File

Tags: shell, text, emacs, tar

I have a long text file that has numbers in front of each of the paths listed in the file like the example below:

```
1) /some/path/here/file.txt
1) /some/path/here/1file.edf
2) /some/another_path/here/2file.txt
3) /some/other_path/here/3file.txt
3) /some/other_path/here/4file.edf
3) /some/other_path/here/5file.edf
...
```

This file continues for thousands of lines. What I have to do is cut the number off the first part of each of these lines so that I could tar the list of files without the numbers interfering. Is there a way that I could do this either using Shell Commands of Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are your friend here. You can do this in emacs or on the command line. In emacs, if you press `C-M-%` (control+alt+shift+5) or run `query-replace-regexp` it will prompt you for a regex to find, and another to replace. If you use `^[0-9]*)` (note that there is a space at the end of this), and then leave "repalce" empty, you will replace the number, the paren, and the space with nothing. If you start at the top of the file, you can type `!` to replace all, or go one by one to check that it's working for a bit first.

In the regexp, `^` matches the beginning of the line `[0-9]` means match a single character in the range 0 through 9, the `*` means "match any number of the previous thing", then the `)` matches a literal paren (in emacs this is the default, in shell you'd likely need to escape this with `\)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
cat list.txt | cut -f 2 -d' ' | xargs tar czf archive.tar.gz
```